Linear combination of Gram matrices with positive coefficients is another Gram matrix
The problem is as follows: let a Euclidean space $(V, (\cdot, \cdot))$ be given, let $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$ be the Gram matrices for bases $(\vec{e}^{1}_i)_1^n$ and $(\vec{e}^{2}_i)_1^n$. Prove that for any positive coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ the matrix $\Gamma := \alpha_{1} \Gamma_{1} + \alpha_{2} \Gamma_{2}$ is also the Gram matrix of some basis.
I have a solution but I'm not sure about it. Please check it for correctness.
Without restricting generality, we can assume that in our space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ we use the standard scalar product $(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) = \vec{u}^T \cdot \vec{v}$. Indeed, if some non-standard scalar product is used, we can find for it an orthonormal basis $(\vec{e}_i^0)_1^n$, and then start expressing all vectors through this basis, i.e., make an isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and the scalar product will already be standard in the second space.
Thus, $(\vec{u}, \vec{v}) = \vec{u}^T \cdot \vec{v}$. That is, if \begin{equation*}
        S_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
            \vec{e}_1^1 & \vec{e}_2^1 & \cdots & \vec{e}_n^1
        \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}.
    \end{equation*}
is the transition matrix to the $(\vec{e}^{1}_i)_1^n$ basis, then the Gram matrix $\Gamma_1$ of this basis will be expressed as follows: \begin{equation*}
        \Gamma_1 = S_1^T \cdot S_1
    \end{equation*}
Same for $\Gamma_2$.
What can we say about the matrix $\Gamma$?

$\Gamma$ is symmetric -- it is obvious.
Is $\Gamma$ positively defined? Let $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an arbitrary nonzero vector. Then we have \begin{equation*}
        \vec{x}^T \Gamma \vec{x} = \alpha_1\vec{x}^T \Gamma_1\vec{x} + \alpha_2\vec{x}^T \Gamma_2\vec{x} > 0
    \end{equation*}

So this matrix is a matrix of some symmetric bilinear form (in the standard basis) with positive index of inertia equal to $n$. By Sylvester's law of inertia we can find a basis in which the form will have the identity matrix: $\exists S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$: \begin{equation*}
    E = S^T \cdot \Gamma \cdot S.
\end{equation*}
That is, $\Gamma = (S^{-1})^T \cdot S^{-1}$. $\Gamma$ is the Gram matrix for the basis $(\vec{e}^{3}_i)_1^n$ formed by the columns of $S^{-1}$.
That's it. Check it please.
I also have a question: there are many ways one can diagonalize $\Gamma$. And there are many bases that have the same Gram matrix $\Gamma$. Is it possible to somehow construct an analogue of the basis $(\vec{e}^{3}_i)_1^n$ (a basis whose Gram matrix is $\Gamma$) directily from $(\vec{e}^{1}_i)_1^n$, $(\vec{e}^{2}_i)_1^n$? Obviously $(\alpha_1 \vec{e}^1_i + \alpha_2\vec{e}^2_i)_{i=1}^n$ is not suitable. It may not even be a basis.
Thank you in advance.

Your solution seems correct to me. Unfortunately, I doubt that there is an easy way to construct the basis $e^3$ that doesn’t involve an iterative procedure — but then, unrolling the Choleski decomposition algorithm (of a symmetric matrix into $L L^T$ with $L$ lower triangular) might provide one of the simplest solutions.
